# Can't catch MySQLi exception if bind_param() has mismatch

Tags: php, mysqli

So if I were to put on `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` before creating the connection, I'd expect it to report all errors in the form of exceptions, which it seemingly does. However, for some reason, I'm receiving an error warning I 
obviously can't catch if there's a mismatch in `bind_param()` for bound variables or types. Here's an example message I'd get if I used too few or many variables to bind.

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Is this a bug with `mysqli_sql_exception`? I could suppress the warning obviously, but that seems a bit hackish. On the other hand, if I do `@`, I'll still get a meaningful message to catch anyway.

> No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement

Still, I'd prefer not to do this if possible, but it seems like the only way, unless I'm completely missing something. I'm surprised I couldn't find any info regarding this anywhere. I suppose I could do something with `set_error_handler()`, but I honestly think suppressing the warning is a better choice for this case.

Comment: I'm thinking what you want is `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)`.

Comment: No, sorry that's not the answer

Comment: You're right! According to the documentation `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` should "[Throw mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php#refsect1-mysqli-driver.report-mode-parameters)", and it appears this is not the case here. I tried it and I'm also getting a warning being produced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is still an inconsistency in the driver. Not every error is translated into `ErrorException` yet, some are still just PHP warnings. It seems that a custom error handler is the only solution.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm actually using PHP 7.1. Maybe they still haven't fixed this.

Comment: You are right, I did the wrong test. So yes, a custom error handler is the only solution

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in [PHP 8.0.0](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75813) - but in the meantime you can do something like this (although, I am sure other solutions exist) to ensure exceptions are thrown. Note, I haven't suppressed the warning - although you can if desired using `if (!@$stmt->bind_param...) {`

```
protected function Bind(mysqli $db, mysqli_stmt $stmt, array $data): void {
    // bind_param can fail and will only generate warning, defect fixed in PHP 8 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75813
    if (!$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($data)), ... $data)) {
        // if bind_param has failed but no db error is set, let this continue and it will trigger exception in Execute
        if ($db->errno) {
            throw new mysqli_sql_exception($db->error);
        }
    }
}
```